# utf8_decode(): Same strings in UTF-8 returns different result (PHP)

Tags: php, utf-8

I have two strings that look absolutely the same in UTF-8.

```
$string1 = "histórico";
$string2 = "histórico";
```

but when I convert them to ISO-8859-1, (it doesn´t mind if I use `utf8_decode`, `iconv` or `mb_convert_encoding`) I get different output for them:

- The string1 converts to histoÌrico
- The string2 converts to histÃ³rico (that is, in fact what I expected for both strings)

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: <?

$cadena1 = "histoÌrico";

$cadena2 = "histÃ³rico";

echo utf8_decode($cadena1);

echo utf8_decode($cadena2);

?>

Comment: For what purpose do you "expect" "histÃ³rico"...?

Comment: well i have to work with ISO-8859-1 strings and they should look the same... but they don´t (in fact if i print them on screen only the second will show the ó character)

Comment: Right, so I'd *expect* the result to be "histórico" in ISO-8859-1, no?

Comment: Probably just how the string is constructed. You should normalize the input first so that escape characters  in the utf-8 byte represention get cleaned up

Answer (score 2):

There are [two ways of creating the character `ó` in Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00F3/index.htm):

- As a single character: `U+00F3`
- As a lowercase `o`, followed by the combining accent mark `´`: `U+006F U+0301`

After rendering, they look identical.

Comment: And how could i convert the U+006F U+0301 character to ISO-8859-1? I´m afraid it has no correspondance (and the same happens with many other characters)

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP's way of handling Unicode strings, but you'll have to *encode* the string into 8859-1, not *decode* it. It may be necessary to [normalize](http://php.net/manual/de/class.normalizer.php) the string first, if PHP's encoding functions can't handle decomposed forms. Sorry not to be more helpful - I could show you the two lines of code it would take you in Python, but I am a complete noob as far as PHP is concerned...

Comment: if i "encode" into 8859-1, using iconv() or mb_convert_encoding() i get the same result...